# How to read length of video file from cmd

Tags: cmd, file-attributes

I have a bunch of `mp4` files in a folder and I want to create a text file with all the names and the length of the files as in:

```
01_Welcome.mp4 00.01.23
02_Tools.mp4 00.03.12
```

I know how to read the names of the files buy how do I get the length attribute? When I click a file the length appears in the status bar, so there should be a way to read that property. And I would like to do it from the command line, not through a third-party package.

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu there you can

```
 ffmpeg -i myvideo 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
```

But in Windows [MediaInfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) is the one option

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows and I was hoping there was some sort of batch magic that could help, but I'll give this MeidaInfo a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows' PowerShell you can do the following to extract length of a single media file:

```
$Folder = 'C:\Path\To\Parent\Folder'
$File = 'Video.mp4'
$LengthColumn = 27
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
$objFolder = $objShell.Namespace($Folder)
$objFile = $objFolder.ParseName($File)
$Length = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFile, $LengthColumn)
```

Iteration over the folder content is left as an exercise for the reader.

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/bad2dbb1-5deb-48b8-8f8c-45e2b353dba0/how-do-i-get-video-file-duration-in-powershell-script)